# Serializing a class containing as a member a boost adjacency_list using boost::serialization

Tags: c++, serialization, boost, boost-serialization, boost-graph

I have a class which has a member `graph` which is a boost adjacency_list `boost::adjacency_list<setS, setS, undirectedS, AINGNodeData, AINGEdgeData> graph;`, would it be directly serializable ? How can I serialize it ? I use boost:serialization.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should not be an issue. The class `boost::adjacency_list<....>` is serializable. See the file

```
#include <boost/graph/adj_list_serialize.hpp>
```

Simply make sure your properties `AINGNodeData, AINGEdgeData` are serializable, the library should take care of the rest. If properties are simple types or containers (e.g. std::string), it would be enough to make sure the proper *serialization* header is included, e.g.

```
#include <boost/serialization/string.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/vector.hpp>
```

Good luck.